# How to make a LAN connection?

Tags: virtualization, network-bridge

I am using Ubuntu on a virtual machine and I want to acces the internet from ubuntu. I'm having a LAN network on the main computer.

Comment: What virtualilzation ? virtualbox or KVM or other ? Either way you need to use bridged networking.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything , just connect to lan network from your host computer. You will see wired connection established in your title bar in vbox, i mean the uppermost bar with setting.

Comment: First please use proper English. Second, that is not true. By default VBox uses NAT, you need to use a bridged network connection.